# How to add a scrollviewer to textblock on window resize?

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I've this situation:

```
<Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ClubController.Club.Stadium.Image}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="Address:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Telephone:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </UniformGrid>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClubController.Club.Stadium.Address}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClubController.Club.Stadium.Telephone}" />
                            </UniformGrid>
                        </Grid>
```

as you can see I've designed a grid with three columns, so the final result is this:

```
[image][default text][binded text]
```

The problem's that some binded text property on the textblock are too long, so when the user resize the window I get the text cutted. I want display something like a scrollbar when the window is resized and the text is cutted, so the user can move the scrollbar and see the complete text. How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
            <UniformGrid Rows="13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Address:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="Telephone:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </UniformGrid>
            <UniformGrid Rows="13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClubController.Club.Stadium.Address}" 
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClubController.Club.Stadium.Telephone}" 
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
            </UniformGrid>
```

Edit, add a style to your textblock (I did not check it works)

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockWithScroll" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
</Style>
```

Now your textblock using the style

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ClubController.Club.Stadium.Address}" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockWithScroll}" />
```

Comment: mmm I've 13 textblocks is possible apply this one time per all textblocks?